# Select Dataframe by Column and give np.NaN for the missing columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"a": 1, "b": 2}])
```

I want to create another dataframe with column "a" and "c" and give np.NaN for column "c". I have something like this, but it throws error since "c" is not in df. What is a clean and working way to do it?

```
df1 = df["a","c"]
```

Comment: ``Df1 = DF[["a"]]`` then ``df1["c"]=np.nan``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.join` to add the "c" column with NaN values to your existing dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{"a": 1, "b": 2}])

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=["c"]))

display(df)
```

The output:

| index | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | NaN |